# react native google sign in - cannot press next, forgot email, or create account

Tags: ios, react-native, google-signin

[image of simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njWAv.jpg)

unable to press the forgot email, create account or next button. When I press them there is no action, it stays on that same signin page. help, privacy and terms work.

wrote the function in the googlesignin.tsx file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-native'
import {
    GoogleSignin,
    statusCodes,
} from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';

export class GoogleSign extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userInfo: null,
        };
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Button title={'Sign in with Google'} onPress={async () => {
                GoogleSignin.configure({
                    iosClientId: '552669576534-ninopsfqvitpk59v9kt42mn0r2e4o37h.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                    webClientId: '552669576534-vpmbo9vbodnaeqghnjai6d0fhcl2enhc.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                    offlineAccess: true,
                });
                try {
                    await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
                    const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
                    this.setState({userInfo});
                    console.log(userInfo);
                } catch (error) {
                    if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
                        // user cancelled the login flow
                    } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
                        // operation (e.g. sign in) is in progress already
                    } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
                        // play services not available or outdated
                    } else {
                        // some other error happened
                    }
                }
            }}/>
        );
    }
}
```

I also have added my inverse url to the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [doc](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin), you might have missed to configure signIn which is mandatory

```
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';

GoogleSignin.configure();
```